# Majority Voting in Ensemble Learning

Tags: classification, ensemble-learning

I have problem reading and understanding Eq.17 (specially that max operator and the difference between J and j) in the following description of majority voting. I know that we select the class that majority (i.e. maximum number of classifiers) select, but how the equation depicts that?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat obfuscating a very straightforward procedure. For class $j$, the sum $\sum_{t=1}^Td_{t,j}$ tabulates the number of votes for $j$. Plurality chooses the class $j$ which maximizes the sum (presumably with a coin flip for tie breaks). So their notation should be something like:

$J=\mbox{argmax}_{j\in\{1,2,\cdots,C\}}\sum_{t=1}^Td_{t,j}$